# ruby on rails rake db:migrate error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

i'm starting to learn ruby on rails using this guide : 
[getting_started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)  , i created my project and database but when i run rake db:migrate i get this error:

> @mona-Extensa-5230:~/rubyDev/Sites/blog# rake db:migrate
>   (in /home/mona/rubyDev/Sites/blog)
>   ==  CreatePosts: migrating ====================================================
>   -- create_table(:posts)
>   rake aborted!
>   An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
>   private method `String' called for#
>   ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0xb7540f30>

thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Looks like you have a line like this in one of your migrations:

`t.String`

Note that the `s` needs to be in lowercase (`t.string`)